# Rightful claim on what exactly?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Balliol speaks to William Wallace:

> Balliol: Sir William, inasmuch as you and your captains hail from a
> region long  known to support the Balliol clan, may we invite you to
> continue your support and uphold our **rightful claim**?
>
> Runner: Damn the Balliol clan! They're all Longshanks' men!

Rightful claim on what exactly?

Source: Braveheart 1995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ***claim*** here refers to a claim to the throne of Scotland. When a king dies, succession can be a messy affair if there are multiple people who claim the throne to be theirs. Any claimant will require support to enforce their claim, or else others will force them out. Here, Balliol requests support for his claim to the Scottish throne, so that he may rule as king, rather than the other people who claim the throne for themselves..